# Plot a polynomial function like on the wolframalpha-website so that it is easy to understand

Tags: r, function, plot, wolframalpha

Plotting a function in the wolfram-alpha-website looks like this:

[image]

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20-%203*x%20-%2010%20&dataset=)

Plotting the same function in R looks like this:

plot( function(x) x^2 - 3*x - 10  )
[image]

The default plot from Wolfram is much easier to understand. I think this is because it shows the x-axis (at y=0), and centers the parabola.

I am not good enough at math to just look at the formula of a function and see where I should center the plot, and I am plotting the functions to learn about how different functions create different lines, so I need this centering to be done automatically, because otherwise I might misunderstand a plot.

Is it possible to create the Wolfram-plot *automatically* i.e. without me telling R where it would be sensible to center the plot?

Comment: there is definitely not a built-in way to do this in base R.  It's an interesting challenge to design an algorithm that automatically figures out the interesting range of a function, for some definition of "interesting" ...

Comment: The `polynom` package offers some functionality here.

Comment: Picking domains and ranges automatically is challenging. Lee Wilkinson proposes one approach in http://www.cs.uic.edu/~wilkinson/Publications/plotfunc.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `polynom` package will create some sensible defaults.

eg.

```
library(polynom)

# your polynomial (coefficients in ascending powers of x order)
p <- polynomial(c(-10,-3,1))
plot(p)
```

[image]

```
 # a more complicated example, a polynomial crossing the x axis at -1,0,1,2,3,4,5

 p2 <- poly.calc(-1:5)
 p2 
 # -120*x + 154*x^2 + 49*x^3 - 140*x^4 + 70*x^5 - 14*x^6 + x^7 
 plot(p2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the desired interval to plot over, as described in `?plot.function`.  Also see `curve` and `abline`.

```
plot( function(x) x^2 - 3*x - 10 , -15, 15) ; abline(h=0,v=0,lty=3)
```

or

```
curve(x^2 - 3*x - 10 , -15, 15) ; abline(h=0,v=0,lty=3)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question so it is more clear that I am looking for a way to do this automatically.

Comment: As far as I know, R does not have built-in way to do this automatically.  However, if you have some idea of what would be "sensible", a function could be written to change the plotting interval automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old post post but I was trying to fit a polynomial curve based on the coefficients of my model.

The original in base R :

```
plot( y ~ x) 
curve(3*x - 2*x^2 + 2*x^3)   ##  random coefficients for easy example
```

I use ggplot2 - so I wanted to use the curve generated from the coefficients rather than a + geom_smooth (This also works but I prefer the curve below)

```
bestfit <- geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = T, size = 1) 

ggplot2 
+ bestfit
```

Instead I created a function with the coefficients above

```
test 
test <- function(x) {3*x - 2*x^2 + 2*x^3}
```

I have then added it as a layer in the ggplot

```
ggplot2
+ stat_function(fun = test)
```

It gives me the same curve as the base plot function but I can add all the additional layers in ggplot

Comment: The code does not produce any ggplot (only a base plot).