# The real line in R

Tags: r, function

Is there a way to define the entire real line as a domain of a function in R? Up until now when I wanted to plot a function, I would first define x using the command:

```
> x <- seq(a,b, by=0.01)
```

where `a` and `b` are numbers enclosing the interval. And then

```
> plot(x,f(x))
```

where `f(x)` is a prespecified function.

Is there a way to define the real line as the domain and skip step 1?

Comment: You can use `curve`, but that just hides step 1. There is no way to avoid that because of the way computer graphics work. There can only be a finite number of points (or objects if you use a vector graphics format) in a plot.

Comment: @Roland, post as an answer (with example)?

Comment: there are some comments about auto-selection of x-axis range here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251653/plot-a-polynomial-function-like-on-the-wolframalpha-website-so-that-it-is-easy-t